# fivestar module get count

Tags: 7, rating

I am interested in getting the average count for a node.
Currently I am able to show the nodes rating with:

```
$fivestar = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_cg_rating', 'basic');
render($fivestar);
```

But I just want to get the count instead of the entire html showing the vote. Just a numerical value.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calc it with formula which is used by Fivestar on theme layer: http://drupalcode.org/project/fivestar.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/includes/fivestar.theme.inc#l132

```
$fivestar = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_cg_rating');
$stars = 5; // Stars count from your field instance settings. Settings can be loaded with field_info_instance() if needed.
$rating = round(($fivestar['#items'][0]['average']/100) * $stars, 1);
```

Comment: this should get me going in the right direction. I'll fiddle around with it. Cheers. +1

Comment: Just an fyi, using $fivestar['#items'][0]['average'] is incorrect unfortunately.

Comment: `$fivestar['#items'][0]['average']` always returns zero.

Comment: Please, dump `$fivestar['#items']`.